# How to automatically mount ZFS external USB flash drive when I insert it

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive, zfs, automounting, nautilus

In Ubuntu 20.04, I installed the `zfsutils-linux` package and formatted an external USB thumbdrive to use ZFS (`sudo zpool create mypool /dev/sdb`). I then changed its mount point to `/media/user/mypool` (`sudo zfs set mountpoint=/media/user/mypool mypool`). However, when I insert this USB flash drive into my computer, it is not automatically mounted. I expected the USB drive to automatically appear in the sidebar of the Nautilus file manager. For example:

[image: Nautilus file manager in Ubuntu]

However, unlike the picture above, the ZFS USB flash drive does not automatically appear in the sidebar of Nautilus. I have to manually run `sudo zpool import mypool` for it to appear. How do I automatically mount a ZFS-formatted external USB flash drive?

Comment: Perhaps you can write a little script that watches for changes in >> lsblks -f | grep zfs << and if it detechts a change, then run a  script that mounts the new device to some mountpoint

Comment: @I.P that's a bit archaic. You'd do that using a udev rule. And usually, I'd expect any modern Linux distro to react to newly appeared file systems appropriately.

Comment: Do you have a pool hosting your `/` mountpoint?

Comment: @freezed No. My computer uses ext4, not ZFS. Only the external USB flash drive is using ZFS.